# How to use backslash on Python?

Tags: line, python-3.7, backslash

I’m trying to write code. I’m very new to Python, and i’m using an interpreter on Visual Studio Code. I’m trying to write multiple lines of code, but the \ isn’t working, or i’m doing it wrong. Example:

```
print(‘hi’) \
print(‘hello’) \
```

I would expect it to work, but it comes up as syntax error the next time I press enter. Is that because I’m doing it wrong? Otherwise, how would I enter many lines of code. Keep in mind i’m using an interpreter.

Comment: What behavior are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: A backslash at the end of a line makes python think that the newline after it doesn't exist. So it would interpret as `print('hi') print('hello') \\`. First off, having two print statements like that is not allowed. Also, a backslash followed by an EOF isn't permitted either.

Answer (score 0):

Separate your statements using a semicolon(`;`), if you want multiple "simple statements" on one line. If you want to know more about simple statements, check out the documentation:

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#simple-statements

The backslash(`\`) is used in the case of logical lines i.e expressions. For example:

```
5 + 3 \
* 4 - 6
```

This would work fine because it is an 'expression' and returns a value. The same doesn't work for 'statements'.

This link, I hope, will clear your doubts on the matter:

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining